# How can I add or remove a tag with ng-tags-input within a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using `ng-tags-input`, and trying to modify the input so that only tags which are permitted can be added. For example, an array contains 'Tag1' but not 'T1', and so when 'T1' is entered in the input bar it is not accepted, but 'Tag1' is because it is 'permitted'.

Thanks.

Comment: What defines a valid tag? Do you have a list of them? Or does it need to match a particular pattern? What have you tried?

Comment: A valid tag is a valid country code (US, GB, CA...) which I have a full string array of, each just a two character string. I want to restrict the possible tags in the input so that the only two char strings that can become tags are valid country codes, as in they exist in the country code array that I have.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there's no built-in way to perform such validation. But I think you can use a different approach:

- Use the `autoComplete` directive to provide the user with the list of valid country codes;
- Set the `addFromAutocompleteOnly` option to `true`, so only tags coming from the autocomplete list will be allowed.

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="countryCodes" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
   <auto-complete source="loadCountryCodes($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

[Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qT7c2alJXi7wrqaKjV6b?p=preview)

Comment: Hi. I have used 'allowedTagsPattern', but if I also want to show the user the reason for any tag to be invalid then how to do that? Can i use 'onInvalidTag' for it? If yes, then can you kindly show me how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case are trying to put a check for Email ID, below is the code. **In case of other validation, please change the validation function accordingly.**

**HTML:**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tagList" add-on-space="true" add-on-comma="true" add-on-blur="true" add-on-enter="true" on-tag-added="tagAdded($tag);" placeholder="Add comma separated email id's" ></tags-input>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.tagList = ['abc.def@gmail.com', 'pqr.stu@gmail.com'];
$scope.tagAdded=function(tag){    
    var textEntered=tag.text;       
    var isVaildEmail=validateEmail(tag.text);
    console.log($scope.tagList);
    if(isVaildEmail){
       console.log(true); //do something
    }
    else{
       $scope.tagList.splice($scope.tagList.indexOf(tag),1); //remove the aded tag from ng-model of the input. i.e. tagList
    } 
}
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```